# Codeigniter $query->row() method not working with string parameter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am making a user login for my library file. But my user_query->rows are not working, not sure how to fix it been reading user guide.

```
$this->user_id = $user_query->row('user_id');
$this->username = $user_query->row('username');
$this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') = $user_query->row('user_id');
```

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-cms\system\libraries\Users.php on line 69
>
> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-cms\system\libraries\Users.php on line 65

```
public function login() {
    $user_query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "user WHERE username = '" . $this->CI->db->escape($username) . "' AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->CI->db->escape($password) . "'))))) OR password = '" . $this->CI->db->escape(md5($password)) . "') AND status = '1'");

    if ($user_query->num_rows() == 1) {

        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'username' => $this->username
        );

        $this->CI->session->set_userdata($data);

        $this->user_id = $user_query->row('user_id');
        $this->username = $user_query->row('username');

        // line 65  
        $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') = $user_query->row('user_id');      

        // Line 69
        $user_group_query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT permission FROM " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "user_group WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_query->row('user_group_id') . "'");

        $permissions = unserialize($user_group_query->row('permission'));

        if (is_array($permissions)) {
            foreach ($permissions as $key => $value) {
                $this->permission[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**New error** I removed password from showing on here

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'admin'' AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(''*****''))))) O' at line 1
>
> SELECT * FROM oc_user WHERE username = ''admin'' AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(''******''))))) OR password = ''***************'') AND status = '1'
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-cms\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do with this line:

```
$this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') = $user_query->row('user_id');
```

Are you trying to set a session? In that case, you need to use `set_userdata()`:

```
$this->CI->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user_query_>row('user_id');
```

Also, I've never seen the usage of row() like you do. I went to [the manua][1]l and saw just this:

> If you want a specific row returned you can submit the row number as a
>   digit in the first parameter.

No mention of using a string as field name. Maybe you mean:

```
$row = $user_query->row();
echo $row->user_id;
```

I believe it can be chained, so `$user_query->row()->user_id` should work.

Edit after comment

Use parametrized queries, it's better and avoids those nasty escaping problems:

```
$user_query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "
user WHERE username = ? 
 AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(?))))) OR password = ?) 
 AND status = ?", array($username, $password, md5($password), 1));
```

Comment: And the permission having error as well not to sure if got login function correct.

Comment: tried it all just got one more error. I put new error on first topic

Comment: Update to solve query problem. BTW, I don't understand how you look for the password: are you using md5() or that complicate sha1 mysql function??

Comment: I am mixing it up in the install model when create user like salt just so its harder to break. I can not seem to get the bcrypt working so making my own.

Comment: Is this correct just not sure if done OK it is on my parent construct area $user_query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->CI->db->dbprefix . "user WHERE user_id = '" . (int)$this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') . "' AND status = '1'");

Comment: ? Are you the same guy logged with another account? Anyway, use parametrized queries